# split dict intro sub dicts when values are numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a dict whose values are numpy arrays as follows:

```
mydict = {
       "key0": array0,
       "key1": array1,
       "key2": array2
       }
```

`array0` and other two have the same length.
I want split `mydict` into two sub dicts, each has the same key as `mydict`, except for each key their value are the first half of `array` and second half of `array`.

Comment: What do you want to do if the array lengths are an odd number?

Comment: It does not matter, if it is odd number, then one dict takes a half and one takes the rest is ok for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split):

```
import numpy as np

array0 = np.arange(4)
array1 = np.arange(4, 8)
array2 = np.arange(5)  # Odd number of elements

d = {
    "key0": array0,
    "key1": array1,
    "key2": array2
    }

d2 = dict.fromkeys(d)
d3 = dict.fromkeys(d)

for key in d:
    splitted = np.array_split(d[key], 2)
    d2[key] = splitted[0]
    d3[key] = splitted[1]

print(d2)
# {'key0': array([0, 1]), 'key1': array([4, 5]), 'key2': array([0, 1, 2])}

print(d3)
# {'key0': array([2, 3]), 'key1': array([6, 7]), 'key2': array([3, 4])}
```

When you have arrays of odd length, this will grant the "first half" the additional one element.  (Length of 5 gets split into 3 & 2.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I am wondering if `np.array_split` can also be applied to split `d` into 2/3 length and 1/3 length?

Comment: Yes, read the docs for [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) and just ask a separate question if you need to.